# How to publish a Powershell module on linux?

Tags: linux, powershell, publishing, powershell-6.0

Currenlty I got

```
PS /data/projects/lesspass-powershell> Publish-Module -Name "Lesspass" -Repository PSGallery -NuGetApiKey xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Publish-Module : The specified module 'Lesspass' was not published because no module with that name was found in any module directory.
At line:1 char:1
+ Publish-Module -Name "Lesspass" -Repository PSGallery -NuGetApiKey oy ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Lesspass:String) [Publish-Module], ArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ModuleNotAvailableLocallyToPublish,Publish-Module
```

#### Project layout

My project is in `$HOME/projects/lesspass-powershell`

```
❯ tree
.
├── Lesspass-Clipboard.psm1
├── Lesspass-Clipboard.tests.ps1
├── Lesspass-Password.psm1
├── Lesspass-Password.tests.ps1
├── Lesspass-Profile.psm1
├── Lesspass-Profile.tests.ps1
├── Lesspass.psd1
├── Lesspass.psm1
├── Lesspass.tests.ps1
├── Lesspass-Validator.psm1
├── Lesspass-Validator.tests.ps1
├── LICENSE
├── makefile
├── PBKDF2_HMAC.cs
└── README.md
```

#### Question

How do I publish the module from my current working directory?

Answer (score 2):

1. I renamed my project's directory to `Lesspass` as it **[must be the same as module you want to publish](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/module/installing-a-powershell-module#use-the-correct-module-directory-name)**
2. Add my project's directory to `$Env:PSModulePath`

   ```
   $Env:PSModulePath = $Env:PSModulePath + ":$HOME/projects/lesspass-powershell"
   ```
3. Then publish

   ```
   Publish-Module `
       -Name "Lesspass" `
       -Repository "PSGallery" `
       -NuGetApiKey $Env:PSGALLERY_API_KEY `
   ```

#### Optionally

Rename file to remove `Lesspass-` prefix, for clarity

```
❯ tree
.
├── Clipboard.psm1
├── Clipboard.tests.ps1
├── Lesspass.psd1
├── Lesspass.psm1
├── Lesspass.tests.ps1
├── LICENSE
├── makefile
├── Password.psm1
├── Password.tests.ps1
├── PBKDF2_HMAC.cs
├── Profile.psm1
├── Profile.tests.ps1
├── README.md
├── tools
│   └── publish-module.ps1
├── Validator.psm1
└── Validator.tests.ps1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can publish from any directory you want. The PSD1 will define the Module Name. If you are developing outside of your Module directory, and you should be, then specify `Path` instead of `Name`:

```
$publish = @{
  Path = "$HOME/projects/lesspass-powershell"
  Repository = 'PSGallery'
  NuGetApiKey = $env:PSGALLERY_API_KEY
}

Publish-Module @publish
```